# C# - WPF class get all resources and fill listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitem

I have class who get all resource names. Here is code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Helper
{

    public static class callResources
    {

        public static ObservableCollection<string> callAllResources()
        {
            var properties = typeof(Properties.Resources).GetProperties(
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);

            ObservableCollection<string> col = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                var s = propertyInfo.Name;
                if (s != "ResourceManager" && s != "Culture")
                {
                    col.Add(s);
                }
            }
           return col;
        }
    }
}
```

in MainWindows.cs have this code:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> resourcesListBox
        {
            get
            {
                return callResources.callAllResources();
            }
        }
```

If I call resourcesListBox I have only one line in queryListBox.

and in MainWindow.xaml have this but it does not work :

```
 <ListBox x:Name="queryListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="155" Margin="18,10,0,0" SelectionMode="Single" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="389"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path = resourcesListBox}" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you need to make your class static so you can call it from your code behind without creating a new instance.

Secondly you need to return something like a list or a ObservableCollection in your callAllResources method and place all the names in this list or ObservableCollection.

then you can call this method from your code behind and it returns a list or ObservableCollection of resource names.

callResources class:

```
public static class callResources
  {

    public static ObservableCollection<string> callAllResources()
    {
      var properties = typeof(Properties.Resources).GetProperties(
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);

      ObservableCollection<string> col = new ObservableCollection<string>();
      foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
      {
        var s = propertyInfo.Name;
        if (s != "ResourceManager" && s != "Culture")
        {

          col.Add(s);

        }
      }
      return col;
    }
  }
```

code behind:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> resourcesListBox
{
  get
  {
    return callResources.callAllResources();
  }
}
```

Xaml code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="Listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=resourcesListBox}"/>
```

Comment: Yep but is this right way to add items ? 

queryListBox.Items.Add(callResources.callAllResources());

Comment: no, items.add only adds one record to the listbox. you want to bind the property called resourcesListBox to the itemssource of the listbox.    
    <ListBox x:Name="queryListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=resourcesListBox}"/>

Comment: Sorry, but i'm new and still no items :)

Comment: hmm oke, what is the datacontext of your window/page?

Comment: I do same what you write as a code nothing different... I will edit the post with current code

Comment: Add "this.DataContext = this;" (whitout brackets), to the constructor of MainWindow.(So under InitializeComponent(); in your code behind)

Comment: You are god! That work and thank you so much! You are good people :)

Comment: Np, you should read this article for future references about data binding in WPF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf

Comment: How can this resource fill text from resource in textBox? Is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151953/discussion-between-thomas-v-and--).

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
stringList.ForEach(item => listBox1.Items.Add(item))
```